# Scrape links from a table with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Scrape links from a table with scrapy. 
The tabe is following format:

```
<tr>
<td> <a href="url">Link name 1</a> and <a href="url">Link name 2</a> </td>
<td> Item 2</td>
<td align="center"> <a href="url">Link name 3</a> </td>
<td> Item 4</td>
<td> Item 5</td>
</tr>
```

I can get text items with

```
rows = hxs.select('//tr')
for row in rows:
    print row.select('td/text()').extract()
```

it returns just the text values.

```
[u' Item 2',  u' Item 4', u' Item 5']
```

I would like to list to contain urls  with Link Name 1 , Link Name 2, Link Name 3

Comment: I don't know `scrapy`, but my gues would be `td/text()` extract should be different to scrap links =)

Comment: td/text() just works for text items only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following XPath to get wanted links:

```
row.select('td/a/@href').extract()
```